# Clients to upload data to central server using WCF, how to verify data was uploaded?

Tags: .net, wcf, client-server, checksum, verification

Less than 10 client computers, each with their own installation have to upload data to a central server.

The client database looks like:

tblSales
- rowGuid
- randomNumber

Central Server database:

- rowGuid
- randomNumber
- dateInserted

I plan to use WCF to send the files to the central server.

**How can I verify the rows were inserted to the server?  What kind of verification options do I have?**

I could return the # of rows inserted and compare that with the # that was sent, but is there any other more robust method?

Answer (score 1):

You can also enable reliable messaging if using a binding like WsHttpBinding that will ensure the reliability of the messages themselves if that is a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Using WCF you're going to be basically calling a function thru a proxy.  Just have that function return a bool true for success or false for failure.

```
bool Success;
Success = MyWCFService.InsertRecord(MyNewRecord);
```